# Can't receive an answer from python socket

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I have a working command for linux that sends a request and gets a response:

```
echo -n -e '\x9e\x4c\x23\x00\x00\xff\xff\xce\xf2\x3b\x18\x80' | nc -u -w 1 -p 11244 127.0.0.1 11235
```

I'm trying to do the same through the python:

```
import socket

IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 11235

MESSAGE = "9e4c230000ffffcef23b1880"
BINARY_MESSAGE = MESSAGE.decode('hex')

print ("BINARY_MESSAGE: [%s]" % BINARY_MESSAGE) # <- message is the same as echo -en does

srvsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
srvsock.settimeout(3) # 3 seconds
srvsock.connect((IP, PORT))
srvsock.sendall(BINARY_MESSAGE)

data = srvsock.recv(4096)
print ("Received message: [%s]" % data)

srvsock.close()
```

I receive a blank responce:

```
BINARY_MESSAGE: [�L#����;�]
Received message: []
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The first problem is that your `nc` command is using UDP, but your Python is using TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nc` command line is using UDP (`-u`).  Your Python code is using TCP (`socket.SOCK_STREAM`).  You want to create a UDP socket:

```
srvsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

You will want to get rid of the call to `connect`, but you will need a call `bind` if you expect to *receive* messages on that socket.  For example, the following code sends a message then waits for a reply on the same socket:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 2222))

s.sendto('this is a test', ('127.0.0.1', 3333))
data, srcaddr = s.recvfrom(1024)
print(data, srcaddr)
```

Remember that UDP is a connectionless protocol.  The other side of this conversation can't "reply" to the message; it needs to explicitly send to the address/port on which the above code is listening.  In Python the other side of this conversation might look like:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 3333))

data, srcaddr = s.recvfrom(1024)
print(data)

s.sendto('that was a test', srcaddr)
```

The above code waits for a message then sends a response back.

Comment: Thank you very much! My bad. It's really about UDP and SOCK_DGRAM instead of the SOCK_STREAM.